# What's the diffence between using theme() and theme_links() to output link HTML?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

What's the difference between using the two options below to output link HTML?

```
theme('links', $primary_links, array('class' => 'links primary-links'))

theme_links($primary_links, $attributes = array('class' => 'links primary-links'))
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a default Drupal installation without any template customizations they will output the same thing.

However, the `theme()` function is essentially a wrapper for the theming system in Drupal. By passing 'links' as the first parameter, you are telling Drupal to look for the links theme whether this be a function or a template. In this case the theme is a function (`theme_links()`) which gets called.

If you would want to make changes to the theme, you could do so by overriding it. For example you could create the function `myTheme_links()` and have it override the default `theme_links()`. If you are calling the function `theme_links()` directly, you would have to change this code to the appropriate theme function. However, if you used the `theme()` function, there wouldn't be any additional change since this function knows when themes are overridden and takes the appropriate action. In a nutshell, using the `theme()` function is the more flexible solution for future proofing your code and probably considered the Drupal way of doing things.

For more information on theming, check out [Drupal's theme documentation](http://drupal.org/theme-guide/6).

Comment: Thanks bkildow. Good answer. I'm learning the advanced side of drupal theming and as soon as I started to read your answer I knew I'd asked a foolish question as I know about theme overriding and the theme function process. I just didn't think before I posted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The short version is:

If you use `theme_links()` you can't override that theme function in your theme using the `my_theme_links` naming convention because you call it directly.

If you instead use `theme('links')` drupal will based on a priority figure out which of the possible theme functions to use. That is a part of what makes Drupal and it's theming system so flexible. Everything can be overridden.

Comment: Not sure how many times I will write this sentence but, thanks googletorp. I knew the answer to my own question as I didn't think before I posted.